# TinyMce using ASP.NET MVC 3 With Razor View Engine - loads but does not display

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, tinymce

I have a simple form using the TinyMce jQuery plugin. When I load the page, TinyMce is supposed to replace my textarea with his editor, but this does not happen. Looking at the html generated, my textarea is there (visibility set to hidden) but no iFrame object was created by TinyMce. The TinyMce object exists, but the activeEditor is null. It is as if I have not initialized it, but I am following the sample code exactly as follows:

//here is where I load the scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.tinymce.js")"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/tiny_mce_jquery.js")"></script>
```

// here is my text area

```
<textarea id="tinymceId" name="content" class="tinymce" rows="1" cols="50" style="width:100%;" ></textarea>
```

//and here is my script code where I initialize it

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tinymceId').tinymce({
       doctype: '<!DOCTYPE html>',
       editor_selector: "tinymce",
       convert_urls: false,
       mode: "textareas",
     });
});
```

Comment: Any javascript errors? Get rid of that last comma after "textareas".

Comment: @Jack, only IE<9 would whine about that, right? :)

Comment: Probably, but correct syntax can never be a bad thing.

Comment: Sorry - thanks. It was actually fine in my code. I removed some other options when I made this post to simplify things and forgot to remove the "," first. It is removed in my actual code though. No javascript errors - looks like it is all working fine, and then nothing shows up.

Comment: I had a similar problem; was either getting an error or the editor just didn't show up.
Turned out that there is a problem with tinymce_jquery_full.cshtml
When the nuget pkg is installed, jquery.tinymce.js is installed to "~/Scripts/tinymce/tiny_mce.js" but the reference in tinymce_jquery_full.cshtml is "~/Scripts/tinymce.3.4.5/jquery.tinymce.js". Had to modify that in a couple of places and tweak the path for content_css, and that springs to life.
Probably not relevant now, but the changes I made are there in case they help anyone else out :-)

Answer (score 10):

Well, the most famous way of being cool nowadays is to use Nuget.

I have written some partial view templates for TinyMCE. (I also push TinyMCE to the feed when it is being updated)

Following article will walk you through for the process :

**[TinyMCE HTML Text Editior & ASP.NET MVC - Setting It Up Has Become Easy With Nuget](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/tinymce-html-text-editior-and-asp-net-mvc-setting-it-up-has-become-easy-with-nuget)**

Comment: Working with partials is always nice for this type of situations.

Comment: I'm trying to use your sample code that I downloaded from NuGet and can't get that to work either. I just created a new project, added the TinyMceJquerySample package to it and made the changes outlined in your article and when I run it, as I step through the tinymce constructer code, I get "$("textarea.tinymce").tinymce is not a function " on the last line of the constructor -(media_external_list_url : "lists/media_list.js"). The only deviation I made was in the @Html.TextArea - I got a runtime error saying the name can't be an empty string, so I gave it the name "tinymce". Any ideas?

Comment: @Laurel there is a sample package as well : TinyMCE.MVC.JQuery.Sample (http://nuget.org/List/Packages/TinyMCE.MVC.JQuery.Sample) install it and you will have an sample running well. That should give u an idea.

Comment: I am using that sample package, but maybe I did it wrong? I just created a new project (MVC Web app) and installed that package and am trying to get it to work with the "Blog" example you have in your article. My reference to your partial view in my .cshtml is as follows: @Html.Partial("tinymce_jquery_full"). It was using this sample where I got the error in my previous post.

Comment: Can you put your sample project somewhere in the cloud and give me the link?

Comment: Just saw what I was doing wrong - your sample code works fine now. It was too stupid of a mistake to share with you :). Thank you for your responses and for putting this up on NuGet!!

Comment: @Laurel sure, spread the word out so everybody can use this awesome nuget package :))

Answer (score 2):

Does it make any difference if you comment out the setting `editor_selector: "tinymce",`?

Another thing to mention:

I am not a friend of the jquery build (tiny_mce_jquery.js/jquery.tinymce.js) for several reasons (it is slow for example, ...). Does it make any difference to use the tiny_mce.js instead? You may load the regular jquery.js on the page too - that is efficient and works well.

Comment: Actually there is no reason I can't use the tiny_mce.js instead. I started out trying to get that to work, but ran into problems so I moved on to the jQuery plugin. I can't remember the problem I had with it, but I will go back and try again. I know more now than I did when I first tried, so maybe I can get it working. Thanks for your response!

Comment: if you run into problems usiong the regular js build - just ask

Comment: I finally got it to work. I removed all references to jquery.tinymce.js and tiny_mce_jquery.js and just used tiny_mce.js  as you suggested and all works fine. Thanks so much!!

Comment: I am glad it works for you now. If this answer solved your problem completely i suggest you accept this answer